# asp.net ScriptManager EnableHistory=True not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have an `UpdatePanel` on a search page on a website I am working on. In order to smooth out the search experience on the page, the search components are wrapped in the `UpdatePanel`. I want to be able to link directly to specific search results, so I set `EnableHistory=true` on my ScriptManager and followed a guide on how to set everything up.

As far as I can tell, everything works as intended on the back-end. My history points are added, my address bar reflects the new history point and everything is good. I hit the back button in the browser and `Page_Load` is fired, followed subsequently by my `ScriptManager_Navigate` event. By the conclusion of all of the events server-side, the state of my response is correct for the history point I went back to.

However, the rub is that the `UpdatePanel` does not change its contents back to the correct history point, almost as if it is ignoring what it is receiving after I press the back button in the browser. This is frustrating, because as far as I can tell, everything should be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I needed to call `UpdatePanel.Update()`